# Confidence intervals for count data of a categorical

Tags: r, confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, multinomial-distribution

I'm trying to analyze the results of a survey question.  The question is multiple choice (but each respondent can only select one answer) and I want to calculate 95% confidence intervals for their responses.

```
A      122
B       55
C       16
D       14
E       13
----------
Total  220
```

If I'm using R, can I treat each choice as a binomial (122 out of 220 chose *A*, 98 did not choose *A*) and use `binconf()` to compute the interval or is there a better method for categorical data?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use [multinom](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Multinom.html) instead.  A multinomial distribution is a generalization of the binomial distribution for independent trials.